# How to have an image appear in a fixed position on the page

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Want to have an image file appear in a fixed position on the page.

Wrote the following code:

```
<style>
.hovering-image{
    position: fixed;
    left: 70%;
    top:20%;
    height: 20%;
    width 10%;
}

</style>

<body>

    <div class="hovering-image">
        <img src="whatever.jpg">
    </div>

</body>
```

However, the image appears elongated and changes proportions as the window resizes. Is there a better way to have the image show up in a fixed location and scale as the window resizes without distorting?

Comment: Updated your tag, remember to use twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: You got an error in Your CSS: `width 10%;` should be `width: 10%;` and this can be Your problem, becouse You didn't give width to this `img`.

Answer (score 1):

Your image changes proportions because you set both the width and height in respect with the window size. Set only the width (or only the height).

Also, you can use `max-width` or `max-height` to specify the maximum dimensions you want your image to have (and `min-width` / `min-height` to specify the minimum dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving only the left and right margins. Giving all the parameters cause your image to distort.

Take this as a reference.

http://www.ehow.com/how_12064024_overlay-image-fixed-position-website.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-size image according to the window use :

```
img {
max-width:100%;
}
```

if you don't want to re-size image give the width in px.